# setting index of join table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, migration

I haven't got my head around indexes, I'm still unsure about following:

So I want to set an index in a join table

```
t.index [:customer_id, :supplier_id], :unique => true
```

Do I need to set a second index the other way round

```
t.index [:supplier_id, :customer_id], :unique => true
```

or is it enough to just set the one? Why would a second one be necessary?

Comment: You only need one index here. It would be sufficient to check the uniqueness.

Comment: Would I then need both without the uniqueness?

Comment: You don't need both. If you have a lot of queries, where you get the suppliers for the customer, you can add an index for `:customer_id`. Or an index for `:supplier_id` if you will often get customers for a supplier.